# I waited two hours before starting my slow-cooker. Will the food be safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety

What I did:

I browned some beef cubes and put them in the slow-cooker. I then added some spices (a lot of spices), tomato juice, olive oil and vinegar.

For all kinds of reason, I waited a total of over 2 hours since placing the meat in the slow-cooker (mostly covered) before turning it on.

I then turned it on high. I plan on cooking the food for at least 7 hours.

Is it safe?

Thank you!

Comment: Since it was marked as a duplicate, I cannot add a proper answer, but your question is very specific, so I think it deserves a specific answer. Meat is usually pretty sterile inside, it is the surface which was exposed to the environment where bacteria grow. Since you've browned the cubes, you've killed the vast majority of bacteria that was on the surface of the meat, so you've probably prolonged the safety period quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is that food can only spend two hours in the 'danger zone'. Leaving it out for over two hours before starting the process of heating it out of the danger zone means that it could now be unsafe.

Cooking it for seven hours on high will probably kill all bacteria in the food, however, it is not the bacteria you need to worry about. The problem is if the bacteria have produced any kind of toxin. These toxins are generally proteins, which will not be destroyed at any normal cooking temperature.

I would recommend following your username and throwing it out.